# How to rotate bitmap with x points on canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to develop a simple game.  My problem is I am trying to rotate an arrow image in the bottom of the screen by following the "x" event from Touch Listener.

Below is my Arrow class:

```
public class Arrow extends GameObject{

    boolean show = true;
    Bitmap bmp;
    Game game;
    Matrix matrix;
    int i = 0;
    public Arrow(Handler handler, int x, int y, int xSpeed, int ySpeed , Game game) {
        super(handler, x, y, xSpeed, ySpeed);
        this.game = game;   
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(game.getResources(), R.drawable.arrow);

         matrix = new Matrix();

    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render(Canvas c) {

            matrix.postRotate(x);
            c.drawBitmap(bmp,matrix, null);
    }

}
```

and this is the `Event Listener`
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

```
    x = (int) event.getX();
    y = (int) event.getY();

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    arrow.setX(x);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
                    touch.move();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

[image: here is a picture that shows what I mean]

How do I write code which rotates the bitmap?

Comment: If you use `imageView`, you can actually just do a simple `mImageView.setRotation(angle)` and calculate angle using the distance of the x value from the center of the screen.

Comment: I'm using a bitmap on canvas. but i dont know how to calculate that

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
//Calculate the rotation of the bitmap.
rotation += 10;
matrix.postRotate(rotation); // or matrix.postRotate(rotation,cx,cy);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

As an optimization, create the Matrix once outside this method and replace the creation with a call to  matrix.reset().
This way the canvas stays directed as before, and you can do more stuff with your [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) like translating, scaling etc. and the matrix's content encapsulates the real meaning of your manipulation.

**Calculating the angle :**

For calculating the angle first you need to know the total progress length(Min value of progress - Max value of progress) of the `Seekbar` that can and the change in the value after seek.

Consider

```
Min of seek bar = 0
Max value of seekbar  = 30
```

Now calculate the angle per unit that is,

```
1 unit = 360/30 = 12.
```

Suppose if the  user has changed the seekbar position from 10 to 20. Now calculate the diff

```
int diff = 10-20 = -10.

rotation angle  = (-10 * 12) = -120;
```

Example 2 :

if the  user has changed the seekbar position from 15 to 10. Now calculate the diff

```
int diff = 15-10 = 5.

rotation angle  = (5 * 12) = 60;
```

Comment: thank you! but how can i calculate the angle from x poision? i'm bad in math

Comment: @Anna Updatd my answer have a look.

Comment: Updatd my answer above

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer to my own question, it rotates the image according to the x input data:

```
float zeroPoint =MainGame.SCREEN_W / 2;

zeroPoint-=x;

float lala = MainGame.SCREEN_W/(180-y);

matrix.setRotate(zeroPoint/=lala, bmp.getWidth() /2, bmp.getHeight());
```